# How to convert Iterator.forEachRemaining to Java 6?

Tags: java

In Java 8 I have this:

```
jsonNode.fields().forEachRemaining(
    item -> map.put(
        item.getKey(),
        getObject(item.getValue())
    )
);
```

Note that jsonNode comes from:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
```

How do I convert the above code to Java 1.6 compliant?

Comment: Does this code compile in Java 8?

Comment: Yes, it compiles in Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to iterate through your iterator `jsNode.fields()` using a loop:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> iter = jsonNode.fields();
while ( iter.hasNext() ) {

     Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> currentEntry = iter.next();
     map.put(currentEntry.getKey(), currentEntry.getObject());

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this class, but I assume `JsonNode.fields()` will return new Iterator each time

Comment: @defaultlocale ah, you may be correct, I scanned the [documentation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#fields()) and must have missed that.  Editing accordingly.